# Error de compilación al ng serve

Tags: angular

Soy nuevo así que si es simple perdón y gracias por su tiempo, al iniciar mi aplicación de angular aparece el siguiente error.

> `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<PostI | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PostI>'.`

La línea del error es la siguiente:

```js
return this.afs.doc<PostI>(`posts/${id}`).valueChanges();
```

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { PostI } from '../../shared/models/post.interface'
    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class PostService {
    
      constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore) { }
    
      public getAllPosts(): Observable<PostI[]>{
        return this.afs
        .collection('posts')
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map(actions =>
            actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data() as PostI;
              const ids = a.payload.doc.id;
              return { ids, ...data };
            })
            )
        )
      }
      public getOnePost(id: PostI): Observable<PostI> {
        return this.afs.doc<PostI>(`posts/${id}`).valueChanges();
      }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si retornas `return this.afs.doc<PostI>(`posts/${id}`).valueChanges().subscribe();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes Typescript configurado de manera estricta. ​Has declarado tu método así:

```
public getOnePost(id: PostI): Observable<PostI>
```

Es decir, que SIEMPRE va a devolver un `Observable` con un `PostI`.

Pero parece ser que la llamada

```
this.afs.doc<PostI>(`posts/${id}`).valueChanges();
```

Puede devolver un `Observable` con un `PostI` o con `undefined`, que se considera un tipo distinto.

Puedes añadir eso a tu método o puedes relajar las restricciones del compilador, añadiendo a tu tsconfig.ts (en la raíz del proyecto)

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ... ,
    "strictNullChecks": false
},
```

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias